# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error ( messed IIS )

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I've looked on some of the same questions around here but couldn't find what i need. I think i messed up my IIS 7.5 ( and i don't even know how - only thing that comes to my mind is that maybe i uninstalled something but i don't remember ). A while back all was working perfectly and now not even an empty site doesn't work anymore. I just get the 500.19 internal error for every one.

Example:

> Error Summary HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related
>   configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> Detailed Error Information
>
> Module    IIS Web Core
>
> Notification BeginRequest
>
> Handler   Not yet determined
>
> Error Code    0x80070005
>
> Config Error  Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient
>   permissions
>
> Config File   \?\C:\Users\stalker\Desktop\BDI\Proiect\web.config
>
> Requested URL http://localhost:80/Proiect/Default.aspx
>
> Physical Path C:\Users\stalker\Desktop\BDI\Proiect\Default.aspx
>
> Logon Method  Not yet determined
>
> Logon User    Not yet determined
>
> Config Source -1: 0:

**web.config file for the site**

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This site was tested on another computer and worked. As all my other site applications. I'm thinking of reinstalling it >.< but maybe you can offer another solution.

Comment: The clue is in the error message: **Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the question has been asked and answered previously on SO...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615296/cannot-read-configuration-file-due-to-insufficient-permissions